# C# VSTO for Outlook - Button that triggers a VBA Macro

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to create a custom Ribbon with a button that triggers a VBA Macro in Outlook 2010. Creation of the ribbon itself works fine but the button doesnt trigger the VBA.

I've tried these solutions: 1) [How-to: Run existing Word VBA Macros from C# Ribbon Addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735815/how-to-run-existing-word-vba-macros-from-c-sharp-ribbon-addin)  but it throws an error since AFAIK Outlook.Application doesn't have a Run() method, contrary to Excel or Word.

```
public void RunMacro(object otApp, object[] oRunArgs){

        otApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, oApp, oRunArgs);
    }

        public void RunChronosMacro(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            RunMacro(oApp, new object[] { "TestMacro" })
        }
```

2) The third answer of this question [Call Outlook VBA code from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156195/call-outlook-vba-code-from-c-sharp) but it also throws an exception `{"Unknow name. ( RESULT : 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))"}`. Maybe this was working in Outlook 2007 but it doesn't in my environnement. As this answer is inspired from Python code, I've also tried it in Python but without success.

```
public void RunChronosMacro(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    try
    {
        otApp.GetType().InvokeMember("TestMacro",
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                    null, otApp, arFunctionParameters);
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(otApp);
                    otApp = null;
                    GC.Collect();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.GetType().ToString());
    }

}
```

I'm quite hard-stuck on this and as I'm not very familiar with C# and Offices add-ins, I don't know what to try next. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

// create outlook object
Outlook.Application otApp = new Outlook.Application();

string[] functionParameters =
            { 
                sTo,
                sCC,
                sBCC,
                sSubject,
                sBody
            };

// Run the macro
otApp.GetType().InvokeMember("YourVBA",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, otApp, functionParameters);
```

For more information, Please refer the link below:

[Need to run/invoke macro from c# code for Outlook Addin](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/f4ba35a9-c22a-40f7-aa0d-78409abc0eb7/need-to-runinvoke-macro-from-c-code-for-outlook-addin?forum=outlookdev)

[How can I run a macro from a VBE add-in, without Application.Run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954364/how-can-i-run-a-macro-from-a-vbe-add-in-without-application-run)

Hopefully it helps you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's the same solution than what I've already tried.

Comment: Your second link was actually helpful, howether the conclusion is that what I try to do is not possible without "hacks" that would be hard to maintain. Do you know about a more stable solution ?

Comment: I'm researching on this problem and will get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: @May.D I found a way! We could use the clipboard to pass messages from one environment to another. For more information, please refer the link below:[Call Outlook VBA sub from VSTO](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f2da0474-e914-4d40-b87f-8291fff56c35/call-outlook-vba-sub-from-vsto?forum=vsto)